# Align checkbox with text in center

Tags: html, css

Been trying to align these textboxes with the text in the center but I just can't get it to work I used `justify-content: center;` but it just doesn't align the checkbox and text underneath each other correctly.

```css
#hyper {
    color: #01539C;
    font-family: BurbankSmallBold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#terms, #agree  {
   font-family: ArialRegular;
   font-size: 10pt;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
        <div id="agree"><input type="checkbox" name="agree"><label>I agree to the CP Rules.</label></div>
        <div id="terms"><input type="checkbox" name="terms"><label>I agree to the <a id="hyper" href="#">Terms of Use</a></label></div>
```

Want it like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggG50.png

Comment: I don't see `justify-content` in your code. What's your desired outcome? What should be in the center of what? Should the checkboxes still line up?

Comment: I took it out cause it didn't do what I wanted but yeah I wanted everything align when you center everything

Comment: updated the code with the `justify-content: center;` so you can see the outcome

Comment: "center everything" - you mean in the entire page? In a parent div?

Comment: I think your main mistake here is that `justify-content` always needs an item to be centered, and an item to center the other item in. In your case, the items being centered are the `input` tags, and the items they are centered in are their parent `div`s, `agree` and `terms`. They don't even know each other, because they live in separate divs. You need to introduce another parent div that wraps both of them. And then another parent div that keeps them aligned to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could introduce a wrapper element with set width that would be the thing justified so the content is still aligned.

```css
#hyper {
    color: #01539C;
    font-family: BurbankSmallBold;
    text-decoration: none;
   }
#terms, #agree  {
   font-family: ArialRegular;
   font-size: 10pt;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
.toggle {
   width: 250px;
}
```

```html
    <div id="agree"><span class="toggle"><input type="checkbox" name="agree"><label>I agree to the CP Rules.</label></span></div>
    <div id="terms"><span class="toggle"><input type="checkbox" name="terms"><label>I agree to the <a id="hyper" href="#">Terms of Use</a></label></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you were going for?

- The outer div represents the area you want your items to be centered in (here stretched to the entire width)
- The inner div is just a normal div, and it is centered in the outer div.
- Everything inside the inner div is just normal html positioning without flex; left-aligned and in two lines as there are two nested divs

For more information about Flex positioning, I can recommend this:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
#hyper {
    color: #01539C;
    font-family: BurbankSmallBold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#terms, #agree  {
   font-family: ArialRegular;
   font-size: 10pt;
}
#checkboxalignment  {
   background-color: lightblue;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
#checkboxes  {
   background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="checkboxalignment">
    <div id="checkboxes">
        <div id="agree"><input type="checkbox" name="agree"><label>I agree to the CP Rules.</label></div>
        <div id="terms"><input type="checkbox" name="terms"><label>I agree to the <a id="hyper" href="#">Terms of Use</a></label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```